# WCF System.ArgumentNullException when there's no argument

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm having a problem with a WCF service method that has no arguments, but when it's invoked I get an System.ArgumentNullException, the error only ocurs when the service is deployed, in debug on Visual Studio everything works fine.

The request:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:CanExecute/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The answer:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="pt-BR">Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
               <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
               <Message>Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String</Message>
               <StackTrace>at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer&amp; number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at XXXX.ExportDailyFile..ctor()
   at XXXX.ExportDailyFile()
   at System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.EnsureServiceInstance(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
               <Type>System.ArgumentNullException</Type>
            </ExceptionDetail>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

When I call using WCF Test Client:
[WCF Test Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Wq9.png)

I searched a lot and couldn't find an answer, I really need help on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the constructor for `XXXX.ExportDailyFile` is passing a `null` argument to `ParseInt32`.  Can you include the code for that constructor?

Comment: There's no constructor defined, that's exactly the problem

Comment: There's always a default constructor.  Do you have any class level fields that are initialized with the `ParseInt32`?

Comment: Yes, I have, and that's the problem, it's initialized by the appSettings and I did not insert the tag there, you can post this as the answer =) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is occurring during the construction of the `XXXX.ExportDailyFile` class when a `null` is being passed to the `System.Number.ParseInt32` method.  That's either happening in a parameterless constructor, or you have a class level field that is initialed with `System.Number.ParseInt32`.  Search for `System.Number.ParseInt32` in your class and you should be able to determine the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, I had a class level field that's initialized by appSettings, and the tag was null there, I put the tag and solved the error.